# Is there a way to add only top-left-border-radius to Shape (not Html) module in Mojs

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, shapes

I want to add a custom border radius to shape module specifically like top left and bottom right border radius and I know it can be done through Html module but don't want to use that because of some technical concerns.

> setting `rx:10` sets all of the edges to radius 10.

any hint or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that a circular shape technically does not have any borders because a border requires an angle that leads onto the next edge and a circle has only 1 edge.

You could try to recreate a circle using lines (if mojs allow bending/curving the lines). If you do go down this route, I would love to see how it's coded.